# Plotting polygons with geopandas and geoplot [Python]

Tags: python, geolocation, geospatial, geopandas, geoplot

I am having some issues plotting a simple polygon geometry. The polygons will not plot with geoplot.

Example of the dataset (maps) I am working with:

| ID | City | geometry |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Praha | `POLYGON ((-736538.020 -1053708.250, -736549.28...` |
| 1 | Benešov | `POLYGON ((-746500.570 -1072617.070, -746491.68...` |
| 2 | Beroun | `POLYGON ((-760901.670 -1049328.700, -760920.06...` |
| 3 | Kladno | `POLYGON ((-776276.650 -1024382.940, -776275.03...` |
| 4 | Kolín | `POLYGON ((-675684.020 -1058939.760, -675695.90...` |

Code:

```
maps = gpd.read_file("Maps/OKRESY_P.shp")
gplt.polyplot(maps)
```

I suspect there is some super trivial solution, like the geometry format... The shp file is from an official source.

Comment: Can you give a little more details please ? What error does this produce ? If failing silently, What environment are you launching this code from ? Is matplotlib inlined ? If not, you need also : `from matplotlib import pyplot as plt` and `plt.show()`

Comment: Just nothing. Prints blank space and <AxesSubplot:>. If I use the datasets in geoplot, such as the contiguous_usa, it displays. So I don't really know what the issue is... 

Here are the geodata I am using - https://we.tl    /t-IehAVgxQbW

Just delete the spaces after tl and download if you want to try :)

Also: I am using Jupyter